# get HTMLDocument from HttpWebRequest without HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: html, vb.net

I'm trying to write a function that returns an "htmlDocument" using "HttpWebRequest" instead of a browser but I'm stuck with transferring of innerhtml.

I don't understand how to set value of "mWebPage" because VB doesn't accept "New" for HTMLDocument

I know that I can use "HtmlAgilityPack" but I would like to test my current code, changing only web request and not to change all parsing code.(To do this I need an HtmlDocument)

After this test, I'll try to change also the parsing code.

```
Function mWebRe(ByVal mUrl As String) As HTMLDocument
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(mUrl), HttpWebRequest)

    ' Set some reasonable limits on resources used by this request
    request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4
    request.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 4

    ' Set credentials to use for this request.
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

    'Here I've tryed many types
    Dim mWebPage As HTMLDocument
    Try
        Dim request2 As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(mUrl)
        Dim response2 As HttpWebResponse = request2.GetResponse()
        Dim reader2 As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response2.GetResponseStream())
        Dim WebContent As String = reader2.ReadToEnd()

        'This is my last attempt
        'This gives Null Reference Exception
        mWebPage.Body.InnerHtml = WebContent


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString) 
    End Try

    Return mWebPage
End Function
```

I've tryed many ways (also import HTML Object Library) but nothing worked :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution on the web and modified my code as below: 
To make it work you must activate reference to "Microsoft HTML object library" (in .Com references)

It is obsolete but it seems to be the only way to make an html document without using webbrowser.

I Hope it helps someone else.

```
Function mWebRe(ByVal mUrl As String) As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(mUrl)
    Dim doc As MSHTML.IHTMLDocument2 = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    ' Set some reasonable limits on resources used by this request
    request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4
    request.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 4

    ' Set credentials to use for this request.
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

    Try
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        Dim WebContent As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

        doc.clear()
        doc.write(WebContent)
        doc.close()

        'To make sure that the data is fully load.
        While (doc.readyState <> "complete")
            'This for more waiting (if needed)
            'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

    Return doc
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is becoming more of a hack by the minute, but this should work.

First, you'll need to instantiate your WebBrowser control at the class level:

```
Private m_objWebBrowser As WebBrowser
```

Next add an Event Handler for the DocumentCompleted Event that contains all your HTML parsing data. You get an instance of the HtmlDocument using the OpenNew method of the WebBrowser control.

```
Private Sub HandleParsing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)

    'Use your code for generating WebContent.
    Dim WebContent As String = "<html></html>"

    Dim mWebPage As HtmlDocument = DirectCast(sender, WebBrowser).Document.OpenNew(True)

    mWebPage.Write(WebContent)

End Sub
```

Finally, you can trigger all of this by wiring up the Event Handler and navigating to some page or Html file on disk (DocumentCompleted fires asynchronously):

```
    AddHandler m_objWebBrowser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf HandleParsing

    m_objWebBrowser.Navigate("www.google.com")
```

Comment: Sorry, this also gives me a null reference exception

Comment: The problem is your HtmlDocument is a null reference.  Obtain an instance from a WebBrowser control.  I've edited the answer to show how.

Comment: This way i get null reference on `Dim mWebPage As HtmlDocument = webBrowser1.Document.OpenNew(true)`

Comment: Edited to show the correct way to get the instance of the HtmlDocument type from the WebBrowser control.

Comment: I'm really grateful for your efforts (it's only for helps from people like you if I learned to write code) but what you suggest is not what I need. I found a solution on the web and I wrote it like answer: it's rusty but it's what I was looking for.