# Multithreading Webbrowsers

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, controls

I am currently making a vb program that i plan to make very big. I have a decent knowledge of visual basic but today i came across something i do not understand. Because of the huge size of my program , i decided to try and keep the program as organized as possible by putting specific subs in modules. These subs consist of httprequest , webbrowsers(control), webclients and alot of loops. In order to prevent these subs from lagging my main application i thread them using threading.thread and i start them from my main form. But this leads to two problems.

- Problem 1: The threads cannot in any way interact with the main form.
  Once the a *httprequest or webclient* collects the information from my desired website, i am trying to make it add the info to a listbox in my main form, So what i did is it typed

`Msgbox("Info Sent")`
`form1.listbox1.items.add(String)`

- The first messagebox will show but although the code right under it runs, nothing is added to the first forms listbox.I am not using delegates to transfer the information, instead, although its not a good habit, i am using checkforillegalcrossovers.
- Problem 2: Threading with a webbrowser.
- Threading with a webbrowser using threading.thread also does not work because it causes an active x error. After looking it up i found that a solution was to use a single threaded apartment but this would not work because i may need multiple threads running off the same sub at once.

One solution that i have found to this problem is creating another form completely and setting it invisible, and since the form is its own thread i do not need to use threading.thread , but the problem comes when i am trying to create multiple threads, or else i can somehow dynamically create the threads and put the subs inside of it programically this method wont work And even if it does i feel that it is sloppy so i will leave this for one of two last resorts.

The other solution is the most simple one in which i just put all of the code in the main form, but if i keep on doing that form1 is gonna become huge and sloppy, doing this wont solve the webbrowser problem either and even when using regions i still feel that something that 1000+ lines deserves its own class.
There must be some solution out there that solves these problems. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: What are you actually doing with the WebBrowsers?...maybe that will help steer you in the right direction.

Comment: I am trying to get the document text from a website.

Comment: For problem 1, you might need to use background worker other than thread when it is related to GUI stuff. I ran into similar stuff when updating a progress bar. I still use thread to solve it. What I did is putting the 'update progress bar' sub in a synclock. Maybe you can try it.

Comment: But you can get that without using a WebBrowser.  Do you need the page actually rendered in your WebBrowser, or are you using .Document?...or something else?

Comment: Ok The code from this link works well [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739371/get-htmldocument-from-httpwebrequest-without-htmlagilitypack)
Now i just need to figure out how to solve the first problem. Is there any other way than using a backround worker?

Answer (score 0):

I checked my code for updating the progress bar, and using a single thread with synclock will NOT work. They way I make it work is perform the step of the pbar each time after a thread is started as I have limited total threads (say less than 5 threads). Thus, even the progress bar steps before the threads are finished, but it will not progress further before new threads started. It is not 100% accurate but it more or less telling the progress

```
 'update the progress bar
                some_form.PBar1.PerformStep()

                ' This while loop is to count the existing running thread, 
                ' and determine whether new thread should start
                While 1
                    Dim t2 = New System.Threading.Thread(Sub() WaitForPermission())
                    t2.Start()
                    t2.Join()
                    If proceed_gen Then
                        Exit While
                    End If
                End While


                'Start doing what I need to do
                Dim t1 = SomeSub()
                t1.Start()

                'End of code, as VB doest not have thread.detach()
```

Correct me if I am wrong, but you probably have to use a background worker. I know this is annoying, but this is the limitation of VB.net.

Or, you can have something like this (pseudo code, not tested)

```
structure some_struct
    'define the strings you want to update, and their status such that 
    'main() knows if you need to update the stuff to the form
    ' You can also put how many threads are running, and the status of each thread, 
    'such that the main knows if all threads are completed
end structure


sub your_sub()
    'Manipulate the website, and update the data structure with
    'proper stuff you need
end sub

sub main(){
    dim t1 = New System.Threading.Thread(Sub() your_sub())
    t1.start()
    ' I am listing only one threads here, but start as many as you want

    'check if there are strings that you need to update to the form
    while 1 
        'check if there are any stuff you want to update from the data structure.
        ' Make sure you use synclock on the data structure, so each thread won't fight each other on accessing the data struct
        dim should_update as boolean = false
        should_update = 'Something thatyou should implement to judge whether you should update the form. 
        'You can start a thread and join it so the thread won't fight with other threads for accessing the data structure

        dim some_string as string
        if should_update
            some_string = 'You may also need a thread to join to get the stuff you need. Dim the string as an array if it is required.
            'You can also try pass by ref

            'if you need to use thread to access the data structure to know if you need to update the form
            form1.listbox1.items.add(some_string )
        end if
    end while
end sub
```

This is an ugly solution, but it will help you do the job...